# Set permission for nearby devices for Android 12+

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, permissions, sumup-payments

In the Android part of our Flutter mobile app we encounter app crashes for os versions >= 12 when trying to scan for an available SumUp device. Although both needed permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
  android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
  tools:targetApi="s" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

are defined in AndroidManifest.xml the permission "Nearby Devices" (which is essential besides the "Location" permission) is always automatically denied on the devices - where manually set it to state "Allow" works fine.
It seems that we have to request these two permissions at runtime as well. This is our Kotlin MainActivity class:

```
import android.Manifest
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            requestMultiplePermissions.launch(arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT))
        }
    }

    private val requestMultiplePermissions =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions())
}
```

In this class we always get unresolved reference errors regarding `registerForActivityResult` and `ActivityResultContracts`, and we don't have any clue where we have to import or update the correct library in order to get this working.

If someone has a working Kotlin class and can tell us where to import the suitable library we would be very thankful.
Our build.gradle config looks like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 33
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 33
```

Comment: To use the activity result API you have to add androidx.activity library.

Comment: Ok, i was able to introduce that library, but in order to run the app MainActivity has to extend AppCompatActivity which crashes my Flutter app again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to skip implementing it in class MainActivity, but use the Flutter package [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) and implement the permission requests directly in Flutter.
This now works fine for the SumUp Bluetooth device (i.e. scanning nearby devices, connecting and location) and notifications.